# Fragment shader for 3D-Textures

Tags: opengl-es, 3d-texture

I want to use a fragment shader to write back into a 3D-Sampler: There is an array of images as input (as uniform sampler3D) to my opengl-es-application and i want to perform some per-pixel operations on it. Can i use a fragment shader to calculate values for a 3D-Texture?

Comment: OpenGL or OpenGL ES? The answer will depend very much on that. In OpenGL you can use [`Image Load Store`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Load_Store). In ES, this is only available in 3.2

Comment: it is openGL ES, and i want to keep the minimum required version as low as possible... Could compute shaders do this task?